# Cannot import JavaTimeModule into Spring Boot config class

Tags: java, spring, gradle

When I try to import `import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule;`

Here is my class:

```
package com.linkedin.learning.linkedinfullstackappangularspringboot.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule;


@Configuration
public class ApiConfig {

@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());

    return new ObjectMapper();
}

@Bean
public ObjectWriter objectWriter(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
    return objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter();
}
```

It does not import. In my `build.gradle` file I have the following:

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310 compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-datatype-jsr310', version: '2.9.2'
```

And the project successfully builds but I still don't can't import this into my class. What can I do?

Comment: Little bit off-topic but shouldn't `return new ObjectMapper();` be replaced by `return objectMapper;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to update your Gradle Project once, that should download the dependencies again. 
Otherwise, download the jar separately and include it as a dependency manually in your project.